# SharePoint Online DEV and UAT Environment Set up

Tags: development

We have recently moved to Office 365 and as part of this we have started using the SharePoint Online. I need to set up both DEV and UAT environments and start Developing few Webparts, Workflows and some Custom Document Libraries. Please let me know which option would be best for me to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy custom code e.g. Web parts to SharePoint Online. You can only [develop and deploy apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930%28v=office.15%29.aspx). You can test these on a local SharePoint (on-premise) farm our you can provision a special SharePoint site collection called developer site (see below).

This site collection can be provisioned from SharePoint Online administration site e.g. https://-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go with *SharePoint Online Plan 1*. This plan provides an extremely budget-friendly way to get access to SharePoint.  It strictly includes SharePoint and provides the following capabilities:

1. File Sharing
2. Document Collaboration
3. Document Collaboration
4. Social Features
5. Workflows and Automation

See this for full comparison:
http://bartholdsonconsulting.com/office-365-sharepoint-boston/office-365-sharepoint-plan-comparison/

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful. How do I develop web parts and Workflows?

Comment: You can do development on-premise and then deploy to SharePoint online. One thing to note is that you cannot develop visual webparts as they need to be farm based. However, you can develop webparts which don't contain control templates and are sandboxed solutions. See this example: https://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1777795/mobile